# Creating a function with multiple arguments that subsets a dataframe [R]

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a data frame named `titanic` with 2021 rows of passengers on the titanic and specific characteristics of each passenger:

```
Class  Sex   Age Survived
1   3rd Male Child       No
2   3rd Male Child       No
3   3rd Male Child       No
4   3rd Male Child       No
5   3rd Male Child       No
6   3rd Male Child       No
...
```

I want to create a function that has multiple arguments that looks something like this:

```
f1 <- function(sex, age, class, survived){
...
}
```

where the arguments are where I input some criteria of the passengers. As an example, I want to be able to input criteria into the function such that

```
f1("Female", "Child","3rd", "Yes")
```

returns

```
     Class    Sex   Age Survived
1534   3rd Female Child      Yes
1535   3rd Female Child      Yes
1536   3rd Female Child      Yes
1537   3rd Female Child      Yes
1538   3rd Female Child      Yes
```

Now, I have hard-coded it and just used an if else statement to cover all of the possibilities.

```
function.q6.1 <- function(sex,age,class,survival){
  if(sex == "Male" & age == "Child" & class == "3rd" & survival == "No"){
    subset(titanic, Sex == "Male" & Age == "Child" & Class == "3rd" & Survived == "No")
  }
  else if(sex == "Female" & age == "Child" & class == "3rd" & survival == "No"){
    subset(titanic, Sex == "Female" & Age == "Child" & Class == "3rd" & Survived == "No")
  }
  else if(sex == "Male" & age == "Adult" & class == "3rd" & survival == "No"){
    subset(titanic, Sex == "Male" & Age == "Adult" & Class == "3rd" & Survived == "No")
  }
...
}
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: There is a data set included in R called `Titanic` which is a 4d array. To clarify your question, can you please edit your question to include the output of `dput(titanic)` so we can work with the data in the same format you are?

Comment: Hi Jon, I added how I loaded my data into the format I am using it in the question above

Comment: We don't have the file you're referencing, and even if you gave a link there's no guarantee that will stay around in the future, so please use the `dput` approach. If it's too much data you could uses `dput(head(titanic, 20))` to share 20 rows.

Comment: Ok, bear with me. I have never used this approach. You want me to use ```dput(titanic)``` for example and copy the results and paste them at the bottom of my question?

Comment: That's right -- that's a common way to share data in R so that your question is reproducible. @Eric did the work of generating some fake data, but it's best practice if the OP can do that step, so that we can all be sure we're working from the same starting place and encountering the same issues you are.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that the first argument is the data frame and the remaining arguments are values for each of the columns in the order that they appear in the data frame or else are named.

There can be fewer arguments than columns in which case for unnamed arguments the first columns of the data frame will be matched against the same number of arguments.  If the arguments are named then the matches will use those names. All arguments after the data frame must either be named or not named. If only the data frame is passed with no other arguments then NULL is returned invisibly.

If there are a non-zero number of arguments after the data frame we get the names or use the first n names where n is the number of arguments after the data frame.  Then remove rows with NA's from dat assuming that those rows cannot match.  mapply compares successive columns to successive argument values returning a logical matrix.  The apply returns one logical value per row and then we subscript by that.

We use the data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end in the test calls.

```
f1 <- function(dat, ...) {
  if (n <- ...length()) {
    if (is.null(nms <- ...names())) nms <- head(names(dat), n)
    dat <- na.omit(dat)
    dat[apply(mapply(`==`, dat[nms], list(...)), 1, all), ]
  }
}
```

Now we run some tests

```
f1(dat, "3rd", "Male", "Child", "No")
##   Class  Sex   Age Survived
## 1   3rd Male Child       No
## 2   3rd Male Child       No
## 3   3rd Male Child       No
## 4   3rd Male Child       No
## 5   3rd Male Child       No
## 6   3rd Male Child       No

f1(dat, "3rd", "Female", "Child", "No")
## [1] Class    Sex      Age      Survived
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

f1(dat, "3rd")
##   Class  Sex   Age Survived
## 1   3rd Male Child       No
## 2   3rd Male Child       No
## 3   3rd Male Child       No
## 4   3rd Male Child       No
## 5   3rd Male Child       No
## 6   3rd Male Child       No

f1(BOD, 1, 8.3)  # BOD is built into R
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3

f1(BOD, demand = 8.3)
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Class  Sex   Age Survived
1   3rd Male Child       No
2   3rd Male Child       No
3   3rd Male Child       No
4   3rd Male Child       No
5   3rd Male Child       No
6   3rd Male Child       No"
dat <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

### Update

Allow fewer arguments than columns and allow arguments to be named.

Answer (score 1):

```
#toy dataset
set.seed(1912)
titanic <- data.frame(class = sample(c("1st","2nd","3rd"),100,replace = T),
                      sex = sample(c("Male","Female"),100,replace = T),
                      age = sample(c("Child","Adult"),100,replace = T),
                      survival = sample(c("Yes","No"),100,replace = T)
                      )

f1 <- function(sex,age,class,survival) {
  titanic[titanic$class==class&titanic$sex==sex&titanic$age==age&titanic$survival==survival,]
}

f1("Female", "Child","3rd", "Yes")

class    sex   age survival
11   3rd Female Child      Yes
15   3rd Female Child      Yes
38   3rd Female Child      Yes
71   3rd Female Child      Yes
85   3rd Female Child      Yes
94   3rd Female Child      Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a data.frame like shown in your question, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
my_filter <- function(sex, age, class, survived) {

  df %>% 
    filter(Sex == sex, Age == age, Class == class, Survived == survived)

}
```

Now `my_filter("Female", "Child","3rd", "Yes")` returns

```r
   Class    Sex   Age Survived
7    3rd Female Child      Yes
8    3rd Female Child      Yes
9    3rd Female Child      Yes
10   3rd Female Child      Yes
11   3rd Female Child      Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

store your columns and conditions in a vector each and then apply the function to the dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

f1 <- paste(f1, collapse = "|")
cols <- c("Sex", "Age", "Class", "Survived")

my_function <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    select(cols) %>% 
    filter(if_all(everything(), ~str_detect(.,f1))
    )
  }
my_function(df)
```

**First answer:**

Maybe another strategy could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

f1 <- paste(f1, collapse = "|")

my_function <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    select(Sex, Age, Class, Survived) %>% 
    filter(if_all(everything(), ~str_detect(.,f1))
    )
  }

my_function(df)
```

output:

```
       Sex   Age Class Survived
1534 Female Child   3rd      Yes
1535 Female Child   3rd      Yes
1536 Female Child   3rd      Yes
1537 Female Child   3rd      Yes
1538 Female Child   3rd      Yes
```